# using moq with asp.net core while unit testing

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-mvc, project.json

I am trying to write a very simple unit test in asp.net core using moq and xunit.
But I am getting a error when I run the unit test.

StackTrace: 
at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior, Object[] args)
   at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior)
   at Moq.Mock`1..ctor()

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, version=4.0.0'.

Below is my code and project.json file.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "Moq": "4.5.22",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "IntegraPay.Domain": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "target": "project"
    },
    "Integrapay.RegistrationApplication": {
      "version": "",
      "target": "project"
    },
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "netcoreapp1.0",
        "net45",
        "net451"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


 [Fact]
        public async void GetAttributes()
        {
            Mock<IRegistrationRepository> repo = new Mock<IRegistrationRepository>();
            RegistrationManager manager = new RegistrationManager(repo.Object);
            var item = await manager.CreateModel("1234");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the preview build of [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.6.38-alpha). https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/27/the-week-in-net-on-net-on-orchard-2-mocking-on-core-storyteller-armello/ lists other packages that are compatible with `netstandard`.

You never want to add `net45x` in the `imports` node for a `netcoreapp1.0` targeting application. The application will most likely fail to load assemblies (like in your case) or will run in to missing APIs at runtime.

Comment: That means whoever wants to use moq with asp.net core 1.0 please use moq version 4.6.38-alpha. the stable release which is 4.5.22 will not work for some reason.

Comment: No idea how those imports are really working, but removing dnx451 resolved it for me